# Flutter Row Text Overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I can't get this to layout properly.

**I'm trying to achieve**

[image: Attached an image to explain what I'm trying to achieve]

This is what I tried so far that gets me the closest to it but isn't exactly right.

```
  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Row(children: [
        PrefixIcon(),
        Flexible(
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            child: TextGoesHere(),
          ),
        ),
        SuffixIcon(),
      ]),
    ),
    TrailingIcon(),
  ]),
```

But `Flexible` with `FlexFit.loose` acts like `Expanded` so the `SuffixIcon` gets pushed to the end even though `TextGoesHere` is a short text.

**I got so far**

[image: I got so far]

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider `..`from `TextOverflow.ellipsis`, this I've got so far with row.

> color container just for visual

[image]

**Widget**

```dart
 Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text("Prefix"),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        "Very LongggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggText",
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.tag_sharp,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text("TrailingIcon"),
          ],
        ),
```

Else, we can use `LayoutBuilder` if we know the prefix and Icons size.

Comment: Hey thanks, I tried your answer but it looked exactly like what `I got so far`. So I tried it in dartpad and it seems like it works great there. I'll accept the answer but I'm still lost as to why it won't work in my codebase.

Comment: Got it. It was because of `Alignment` I had. Thanks for your help!